# Как вывести изображение в tableview из JSON?

Tags: json, ios, swift, xcode, swift4

Как вывести изображение в `tableview` из JSON?

[image]

Comment: Зависит от структуры json и того, как это там закодировано (base64?). Приведите пример вашего json, иначе вопрос слишком неконкретный.

Comment: Добавил изображение

Comment: Ну, ок. Делаете так: а) читаете из json имя файла б) отображаете файл с диска. У вас с какой частью вопроса проблемы или всё целиком непонятно?

Comment: Да, если честно целиком, лучше бы привести пример

Answer (score 1):

Примечание:

Код картинкой никогда не выкладывайте.

Ответ:

В json вы храните только ссылку на само изображение.

Для непосредственной скачки изображения используйте запрос на скачку изображения.

1. Через `URLSession`
2. Используя сторонне библиотеки: [Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher).

Comment: Спасибо за вашу подсказку, сейчас выложу решение которое довольно простое

Answer (score 0):

Как по мне одно из простейших решений, без подключения сторонних библиотек

```
let dn = arrData[indexPath.row]
    let img_url = URL(string:"https://abctv.kz\(dn.image)")
    let data = try? Data(contentsOf: img_url!)
    if let imagedata = data{


        cell.newsimage.image = UIImage(data: imagedata)
    }
```